# MVC3 & EF. Interface for TDD

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, tdd

Can somebody please explain:

1. I am using MVC3/C#/Razor to build a project to get used to using MVC.
2. I am using the inbuilt account controller.
3. I am storing the account data in my local SQL database using Entity Framework to connect.
   **How can I easily generate interfaces for EF?**
4. SO FAR I am using the plugin from: http://blog.johanneshoppe.de/2010/10/walkthrough-ado-net-unit-testable-repository-generator/#step1

This allows me to have an interface for my entities already created. 
However, I know that I have to change my `HomeController` arguments to accept either the real repository or a fake one for testing.

I am completely lost!

Comment: did you sort out how you get your controller work with a parameterless constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at these. They will help and get you started :

http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416511(VS.98).aspx

For dependency injection, you can follow these steps :

`Install-Package Ninject.MVC3` with nuget to your ASP.NET MVC 3 project (if your app is on version 3). This will basically do everything.

Then have the following on your controller :

```
    private IMyModelRepository _myrepo;

    public HomeController(IMyModelRepository myrepo)
    {
        _myrepo = myrepo;
    }
```

Go to **NinjectMVC3.cs** file inside App_Start folder and add the following code to inside `RegisterServices` method :

```
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel) {

        kernel.Bind<IMyModelRepository>().To<MyModelRepository >();

    }
```

Fire up your app and you should be up and running.

Comment: Thank you, very useful! I used something other than ninject in the end, but the basis was the same.

Comment: I would go with the repository pattern as they did on the examples.

Comment: What would be the easiest way of implementing a repository pattern for say an entity model containing the account controller? I can create it by hand, but it would take a long time to do it for all the classes that the account controller creates

Comment: @RawryLions well, there is a nuget package called **MvcScaffolding** http://nuget.org/List/Packages/MvcScaffolding It automates the basic parts. Here is a good video for you http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM13 But I am not much of a fan of this process.